# Best way to approach C++ pointers in C# without using unsafe

Tags: c#, c++

In my case , I have bunch of values of same type , let's say `floats` :

```
        float value1 = 1.2f;
        float value2 = 1.5f;
        float value3 = 2.3f;
```

Now I need a pointer or a reference value can get a instance of this floats and do operations on it.

in C++ :

```
    float* float_reference;
```

Now I want to set float_reference to `value1`
So in my functions every computation put result in value1.

**Notes :**
- I don't want to use classes
- I don't want to use ref keyword in a functions
- I don't want to use unsafe keyword

I just need to do it as I said like C++ , Is there any other way around ?

**EDIT 1 : This is why I can't use unsafe , Here's Example :**

```
using System.Windows;


namespace ValueUpdater
{

    public unsafe partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //// need to assign one of floats to reference object
        }

        float value1 = 1.2f;
        float value2 = 1.5f;
        float value3 = 2.3f;

        float* value_ref; ////// Can't Make this pointer!

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /// Need to change the reference here
            fixed (float* value_ref = &value3) {
                *value_ref += 2;
            };
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /// Need to change the reference here
            /// But can't use value_ref = &value3 without re-initalize
             fixed (float* value_ref = &value3)
            {
                *value_ref -= 2;
            };

        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Output.Content = value3.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="ValueUpdater.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ValueUpdater"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="354.017" Width="368.698">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Add 2" Margin="0,28,27,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Sub 2" Margin="0,55,27,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="Reset" Margin="0,83,27,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Print" Margin="0,0,27,20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
        <Label x:Name="Output" Content="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Try following : uint output = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(value1),0);

Comment: @jdweng that does something completely different...

Comment: Can you explain why you do not want to use the C# language as it usually works? Are you passing these values to a C++ function?

Comment: "I just need to do it as I said like C++ " - `ref float` **is** the equivalent in C#; `ref float float_reference = ref value1;` (safe C#) is virtually identical to `float* float_ptr = &value1;` (unsafe C#) - the *only* difference is that the GC understands the first version, so it doesn't need pinning etc; I'd really love to understand why you don't want to use `ref`, when it *is* the equivalent code (note: `ref` is *usually* used with parameters etc, but: ref-locals are a thing)

Comment: @Marc Gravell : I know exactly what it does and what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @PaulF No , I have a singleton class which is a shader compiler (custom lang) , I have 5 float value which are dependent in calculation. So there's only one slider , I want user assign one of this 5 to slider and slider change selective float value then compile the shader.

Comment: @jdweng they've edited the post; there's still nothing in here that would require `BitConverter`

Comment: You need to enable unsafe code in your project settings to use unsafe code.

Comment: @Mateusz I did , pointers cannot be used like c++ as global object.

Comment: @Marc Gravell : You do not know what the OP really wants.  I think he wants to manipulate the bits in the floating point number.

Comment: @jdweng there is literally **nothing** in the question that could lead us towards that conclusion, but: if we accept that premise: I'd still say that `BitConverter` is probably a bad solution these days - a memory-marshal cast over a constructed span (you can *very* efficiently create a span of length one over a field) allows you to treat any value type as a `Span<byte>` (of the byte-length of the underlying struct) for two-way access to the raw bytes of the value - `Span<byte> bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<float, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref value1, 1));`

Comment: It's very hard to see what problem you actually are trying solve because of the unhelpful names of your entities. So I can't see the meaning of relationship between `value1` and `value_ref`. I think this is going to lead to poorer quality answers for this question. Because a good answer would challenge your assumption that pointers are required. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key usage in the question is this:

```cs
        float value1 = 1.2f;
        float value2 = 1.5f;
        float value3 = 2.3f;

        float* value_ref; ////// Can't Make this pointer!

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            fixed (float* value_ref = &value3) {
                *value_ref += 2;
            };
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            fixed (float* value_ref = &value3)
            {
                *value_ref -= 2;
            };

        }
```

In that code, you are *always* updating `value3`. If we assume that this code is illustrative and that you *intended* to update indirectly via `value_ref`; we can't keep a `ref float` as a field (even inside a `ref struct`), so fundamentally, I think the best way to reconsider this is via an array, i.e.

```cs
float[] values = new [] {1.2f, 1.5f, 2.3f};
int value_index;
```

Now we can use:

```cs
values[value_index] += 2;
...
values[value_index] -= 2;
```

Not quite the same as the C++, but: very effective and simple.

Comment: Sorry marc but the code was why I can't use unsafe not my real code , I have a singleton class , Using an array is a good idea , I liked it but Still I think it should be done in a more clear way . thanks , temporary I accept your method.

Comment: @J.Mcgill the thing you *want* doesn't exist; you can't store `ref float` as a field, and storing `float*` is *possible*, but requires lots of consideration re pinning, as C# has a compacting GC that can only respect *managed* references (`ref float`), not *unmanaged* references (`float*`); indirection via an array (or span) is therefore probably your best bet

Comment: Now i see why C++ is the best  :)

Comment: @J.Mcgill ooh, them's fightin' words :) btw, if you allocated this as unmanaged memory, or took a GC pin against it, you *could* store the pointer directly; that doesn't mean that it is a *good way of solving the scenario*, though

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to use classes - I don't want to use ref keyword in a functions - I don't want to use unsafe keyword

Nope; those are the three options for conveying state in a reference-like way:

1. unmanaged pointers (`unsafe`)
2. managed pointers (`ref`)
3. indirectly as fields on a reference-type (`class`)

You *could* also use indirection via an `float[]` array, `Span<float>`, or `Memory<float>`, but then you also need to convey the index; frankly, those are all just indirect ways of getting a managed pointer to a value, so they're really just special cases of "2".

Comment: so Can I be **SURE** only these options are possible ?

Comment: IMHO if OP doesn't want to use `ref` and `class` the only thing left is unmanaged pointers. GC pins might work as well but actually using these might be painfull.

Comment: @Mateusz I don't mean this disparagingly, but: most times I see people use unmanaged pointers in C#, they're a: incorrectly implemented, and b: unnecessary; I'd *really* rather understand the intended use-case before pushing people in that direction; *usually*, you should prefer them in the order from the bottom of the list upwards, i.e. "fields on a class" first, "ref" second (and I'm including arrays/spans/etc in here), "unmanaged pointers" only as a last resort

Comment: @MarcGravell I completely agree with you on that one. I was just thinking about using GC pins instead of unmanaged pointers.